# Strictly Convex function (Help with Durrett's exercise)

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis, martingales, random-walk, independence

> Suppose $\{\xi_{i}\}$ be i.i.d r.v.'s, and $\text{Var}(\xi_{1})>0$. Let $\phi(\theta) = E\exp(\theta\xi_1) < \infty$ for $\theta \in (-\delta,\delta)$, $\delta >0 $, and let $\psi(\theta) := (\log\phi(\theta) )$ and $S_n = \sum^n_{i=1}\xi_{i}$
>   $\textbf{(a)}$ Prove that $\psi$ is strictly convex;
>   $\textbf{(b)}$ Show that $E\sqrt{X^\theta_n} \rightarrow 0$ and $X^\theta_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. with $X^\theta_n := \exp(\theta S_n - n\psi(\theta))$.

This is the original question from the "Probability: Theory and Examples by Rick Durrett" Chapter5 Exercise 7.4. https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf

My attempt:

$\textbf{(a)}$ 
To show $\psi$ is strictly convex that means we should show $\psi^{''} (\theta) > 0$. Since $$\psi^{'}(\theta) = \frac{\phi^{'}(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}$$, then
$$\Big(\frac{\phi^{'}(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}\Big)^{'} = \frac{\phi^{''}(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)} - \Big(\frac{\phi^{'}(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}\Big)^{2}$$

From this step, I can not show why $$\frac{\phi^{''}(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)} - \Big(\frac{\phi^{'}(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}\Big)^{2} > 0$$

$\textbf{Can I get some  helpes from how to show the last inequality holds?}$

$\textbf{(b)}$ 
$$ \sqrt{X^\theta_n} = \exp(\theta/2 S_n - n/2\psi(\theta))$$
$$\Rightarrow \sqrt{X^\theta_n} = \sqrt{X^{\theta/2}_n}\exp(n\psi(\theta/2)- \psi(\theta)/2)$$
By $\psi(\theta)$ is strictly convex from $\textbf{(a)}$ and $\psi(0)=0$, so $\psi(\theta/2) - \psi(\theta)/2 < 0$, so we have 
$$E\sqrt{X^\theta_n} = E \sqrt{X^{\theta/2}_n}\exp(n\psi(\theta/2)- \psi(\theta)/2)$$

$\textbf{I know $X^{\theta/2}_n$ is a martingale, but how can I conclude that $E\sqrt{X^\theta_n} \rightarrow 0$ from the above equality}$ 
$\textbf{and how to use $E\sqrt{X^\theta_n} \rightarrow 0$ to get $X^\theta_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s.?}$

Thank U!

Comment: For (a), it suffices to show that $$\mathbf{E}[\xi_1^2 e^{\theta\xi_1}]\mathbf{E}[e^{\theta\xi_1}] > \mathbf{E}[\xi_1 e^{\theta\xi_1}]^2. $$ Does this remind you of any familiar inequalities?

Comment: @SangchulLee emmmmmmmm, I am so sorry, I cannot get the point...

Comment: Let $Y=\xi_1^2 e^{\theta\xi_1}$ and $Z=e^{\theta\xi_1}$. Then by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have $$\mathbf{E}[Y]\mathbf{E}[Z] \geq \mathbf{E}\big[\sqrt{YZ}\big]^2 = \mathbf{E}\big[|\xi_1|e^{\theta\xi_1}\big]^2 \geq \mathbf{E}\big[\xi_1 e^{\theta\xi_1}\big]^2. $$ This almost proves the desired claim except that the inequality should be strict. Now using the condition that $\xi_1$ is not constant (in a.s.-sense, of course), you can show that at least one of the above inequality becomes strict.

Comment: Alternatively, define a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mu(A) = \mathbf{E}\big[\mathbf{1}_{\{\xi_1\in A\}}e^{\theta\xi_1}\big]/\mathbf{E}\big[e^{\theta\xi_1}\big]$. Then $$\frac{\phi''(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x^2\,\mu(dx), \qquad\frac{\phi'(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}=\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\,\mu(dx).$$ Now using the fact that $\mu$ is not a point mass (which follows from $\mathbf{Var}(\xi_1)>0$), one can utilize the Jensen's inequality to show that $\psi''(\theta)>0$.

Comment: @ Sangchul Lee Thanks a lot! I got it for the first method, the strict is easy to prove, but for the alternative method, how to apply Jensen's inequality? The only thing left is not $\frac{\phi^{''}(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)} - \Big(\frac{\phi^{'}(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}\Big)^{2} > 0$? If I want to use Jensen's inequality, I need to know the function is convex; I am a little confused here.

Comment: Once you check the identities above, notice $x\mapsto x^2$ is a strictly convex function and $\mu$ is a probability measure. So $$ \frac{\phi''(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}=\int x^2\,\mu(dx)\geq\left(\int x\,\mu(dx)\right)^2=\left(\frac{\phi'(\theta)}{\phi(\theta)}\right)^2,$$ and since $\mu$ is not a point mass, the inequality is strict by the equality condition of Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank U :)  I got you. It is a good idea to define a new  measure and use Jensen's inequality solve the question.

Comment: @SangchulLee May I ask you about my second questions? how can I show $E\sqrt{X^\theta_n} \rightarrow 0$ from $E\sqrt{X^\theta_n} = E \sqrt{X^{\theta/2}_n}\exp(n\psi(\theta/2)- \psi(\theta)/2)$. How can I treat the quantity $E \sqrt{X^{\theta/2}_n}$. Thank u~

Comment: Since $X^{\theta}_n$ is a martingale, it converges a.s. by the martigale convergence theorem. Also, direct computation tells that $$\mathbf{E}\big[\sqrt{X^{\theta}_n}\big] = \exp\Big\{n\Big(\underbrace{\psi(\tfrac{1}{2}\theta) - \tfrac{1}{2}\psi(\theta)}_{<0}\Big)\Big\},$$ where the exponent is negative by the strict convexity of $\psi$. So this expectation converges to $0$. The a.s.-convergence to $0$ then follows by Fatou’s lemma.

Comment: @SangchulLee THANK YOU! Does the $E\sqrt{X^{\theta/2}_{n}}$ converges to $1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? How to derive $E \sqrt{X^{\theta/2}_n}\exp(n\psi(\theta/2)- \psi(\theta)/2)$ to $E \exp(n\psi(\theta/2)- \psi(\theta)/2)$? :)